# Unable to access value from array with objects in React native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm unable to access value's from a state array filled with objects.

I got the values when I stored them in an array, but when I try to `console.log` the state, it prints out: `[Object Object]`.
I have tried the following to get the value, example:

```
var data=[{"coordinate":{"longitude":73.8679075241089,"latitude":18.515422222637756},"key":0,"color":"#ffc130"}];

console.log("data"+data[0].coordinate.longitude);
```

This is how I tried to get the value in React Native:

```
    console.log("location "+JSON.stringify(this.state.markers));
    var data=JSON.stringify(this.state.markers);
    console.log("datamap"+JSON.parse(data));
    var dataparse = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("data parse "+this.state.markers[0].coordinate.latitude);
```

This is where I declared the array:

```
class DefaultMarkers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      region: {
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      },
      markers: [],
    };
  }
```

I want to store the latitude and longitude in an array.

Comment: `this.state.markers[0].coordinate.latitude` should work if `data` in your first snippet corresponds to `markers`. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I  already tried    ```this.state.markers[0].coordinate.latitude```   @Tholle but i get the error object not found and yes I'll create an example in snack .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **JSON.parse()** and **JSON.stringify()** to parse it

```
const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.markers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your console.log, separate two values with the comma instead concatenating them.

**Change from**

```
console.log("location "+JSON.stringify(this.state.markers));
```

**To**

```
console.log("location ", JSON.stringify(this.state.markers));
```

Hope you will be able to print the value.

Comment: The problem is not consoling the value I need to parse it to get the coordinates.